# Javascript Search - Diacritics / Accented characters

Tags: javascript, function, search, arguments, diacritics

I've got a javascript search filter of li items running (no problems), but in the instance I've got, I need it to ignore (or replace) accented characters - at present, a search for 'Me' works for 'Mexico', but not 'México' - ideally 'é' would be seen as 'e' - same applies for various characters.

I'm pretty sure I'll need a function that replaces these characters - of which quite a few articles are very helpful, but I'm a JS novice and not sure where I would need to apply the function to my existing code (or if that is indeed the best approach).

Current code is as follows (for the basic search filter)...

```
<input style="padding: 10px; width: 45%;" type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="searchFunc()" placeholder="Search names..."/>

function searchFunc() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, p, i;
input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("my_list");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Apologies in advance if there's something already out there, all the questions I've found thus far haven't dealt with applying it to my type of code.

Many thanks in advance.